# How can I debug my app's production certificate for push notifications

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification

As far as I know, the only way to build an app to use the production certificate for push notifications is to make an Ad hoc build or an app store build.

how do I then debug one of these builds ?

I get a cannot connect to the app when i try to attach to process.
I  have tried changing the archive scheme to 'debug' also

Comment: Do you have the capacity to run a query against where you store the devices push notification token? This will help me provide an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The production certificate for push notifications you created(Existing) will works for both App Store and Ad-Hoc builds.

You can Debug them using Xcode by attaching device.for that you have to create Development push notifications certificates.

For testing Ad-Hoc builds you can put Alerts, Local notifications so can check contents.

Comment: i want to test my existing production certificates though

Comment: You need to create a certificate for Sandbox and Production to test it. As per the documentation (APNs): https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html

Answer (score 0):

I needed to get my Push token from an ad-hoc installation.
to do this I copied the token string to UIPasteboard then used that to target the production device for testing - still can't debug, but can see if the push works properly

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can't do this, I guess it's one of those release and hope for the best things